# How can I fix migrating error while creating a database in models.py in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I've started to learn Django using the No starch Python Crash Course. While going through the steps to code the 'entries', I cannot migrate the database.
The error is shown. I'm using python 3.7 and Django 2.0.7

I've tried using python 3.6 but its still not working

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "E:\Users\HCL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
 packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "E:\Users\HCL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "E:\Users\HCL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "E:\Users\HCL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "E:\Users\HCL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "E:\Users\HCL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "E:\Users\HCL\Desktop\learning_log\learning_logs\models.py", line 10, in <module>
    class Entry(models.Model):
  File "E:\Users\HCL\Desktop\learning_log\learning_logs\models.py", line 11, in Entry
    topic =  models.ForeignKey(Topic)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
```

Comment: You miss `on_delete` argument on `ForeignKey`. Please read the error.

Comment: Make sure you are using the same version django as which is used in the tutorial

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change this line in your model `Entry`

```
topic =  models.ForeignKey(Topic)
```

to

```
topic =  models.ForeignKey(Topic,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```